# (Python) Using pythonnet to call a DLL function (C#) which expects Type ArrayList

Tags: c#, python, .net, overloading, python.net

I am trying to run a function named "functionName" from a DLL while calling it from a python project. I already have control over many of the DLL's functions but when running "functionName" I believe I have issues with pythonnet's List implementation of C#'s Array List.

The line from the DLL which I am trying to call

```
public int functionName(ArrayList data)
```

Currently I have tried to create a python ArrayList through:

```
from System import Int32
from System import Array

data1 = [Int32(x) for x in data1]                # data1 is a list
data1 = Array[Int32](data1)                      # ArrayList Expecting 8x Arrays to be added

import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Collections')
from System.Collections.Generic import List      # Avoids Deprecation

Py_Array = System.Collections.Generic.List[Array[Int32]]()
Py_Array.Add(data1)
...
Py_Array.Add(data1)                              # 8 times total

DLL.functionName(Py_Array)
```

The outcome has always been:

```
TypeError:  No method matches given arguments
```

I have tried a lot of different ways to fix this, and I believe the issue may belong to System.Collections.Generic.List does not match the expected type of ArrayList for C#.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit #1**

I found that there is also a:

```
System.Collections.ArrayList()
```

But this has no solved the issue for Method Matching giving Arguments

Comment: did you try forcing method signature via `Overloads` or Reflection? http://pythonnet.github.io/

Comment: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/265

Answer (score -1):

Solution was to use python to call a function which was written in a C# DLL which takes the types and functions from the first dll.

Annoying but not sure how else to reference custom types created in C# dlls from python.